# Get file size from Asset

Tags: android, file, size, assets, fileinputstream

Hi I want to acces my bin file from asset folder and read file size in android.This code work for ZIP file but did not work BIN file.

```
    try {
        InputStream is = context.getAssets().open("test.bin");
        int size = is.available();
        byte[] buffer = new byte[size];
        is.read(buffer);
        is.close();

    } catch (Exception e) { throw new RuntimeException(e); }
```

**size** is always 0.How can I get bin file size correctly? Thanks

Comment: you dont need it, simply read your data in a loop till `is.read()` method returns `EOF`

Comment: How I dont understand? @pskink

Comment: http://tutorials.jenkov.com/java-io/inputstream.html#read-byte-array